# Displaying events by Month with Lambda

Tags: c#

I am displaying a list of events by day from SQL database using the code:

```
IEnumerable<EventInstance> distinctDate = instances
             .GroupBy(e => e.StartDate.Date)
             .Select(group => group.First());

foreach (var instance in distinctDate)
            {
                // code to display here
            }
```

What I am trying to do is divide them up by month on the page, so in between each month going down the page, i can put the Month Heading in a H3 tag

Comment: `GroupBy(e => e.StartDate.Date.Month)`?

Comment: If you are selecting the data from a database, why dont you sort it then? Something like `SELECT eventDate FROM table WHERE 1 ORDER BY MONTH(eventDate), DAY(eventDate)`? Oh alright. Solution from @CodeCaster looks good.

Comment: I tried this but its only giving the first event for each month and not displaying all the events in that month

Comment: Isn't that because you are then calling `First()`?

Comment: @Rifki that's because you have this `.Select(group => group.First());`. Simply remove this line of code and group your values by month not by date.

Comment: @CodeCaster More likely `GroupBy(e => new { e.StartDate.Month, e.StartDate.Year })` so the dates from different years don't get grouped together.

Answer (score 3):

If you want one event for each day then grouped by month I think this is what you are looking for.  Note you have to also group by year to avoid lumping dates from different years together.  I also added a order by in there to make sure the events are in order by date.

```
var distinctDate = instances
    .GroupBy(e => e.StartDate.Date)
    .Select(grp => grp.First())
    .OrderyBy(e => e.StartDate.Date)
    .GroupBy(e => new { e.StartDate.Year, e.StartDate.Month });
```

Then you would do something like this

```
foreach(var monthGrouping in distinctDate)
{
    var month = monthGrouping.Key.Month;
    foreach(var singleDayEvent in monthGrouping)
    {
        var date = singleDayEvent.StartDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: .. So I have this    .GroupBy(e => e.StartDate.Month)
                 .Select(group => group.First()) ; and it's giving me just the frst date from each month because I have the line with .First() but if I remove that line  i get 'An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) erroe

Comment: That's because without the `Select` you get a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, YourItemType>>` instead of `IEnumerable<YourItemType>`.  So you need to adjust how you iterate the items similarly to how I am in my answer.